# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() while writing pandas xml

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to write an XML file from a pandas DF which comes from a Spark DF.
So, I create the Spark Dataframe:

```
columns = ["key","value"]
data = [("xy", ["value1", "value2"]), ("xy", ["value3", "value4"]), ("yx", ["value5", "value6"]), ("yx", ["value7", "value8"]), ("xx", ["value7", "value8"]), ("xx", ["value11", "value15"]), ("xz", ["value11", "value15"]), ]
```

I convert it to a pandas Df:

```
pandasDf = df.toPandas()
```

When I try to write it to an xml file, this is the traceback:

```
pandasDf.to_xml()

The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If I try to create a pandasDf from data and columns, the to_xml() function works, but I need to create before a spark DF for my use case.
Is there a workaround?

Full traceback:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2082251659156457> in <module>
----> 1 pandasDf.to_xml("my_xml.xml")

/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-08e6e056-b785-413d-82d1-61188028128b/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_xml(self, path_or_buffer, index, root_name, row_name, na_rep, attr_cols, elem_cols, namespaces, prefix, encoding, xml_declaration, pretty_print, parser, stylesheet, compression, storage_options)
   2984         )
   2985 
-> 2986         return xml_formatter.write_output()
   2987 
   2988     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-08e6e056-b785-413d-82d1-61188028128b/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/xml.py in write_output(self)
    259 
    260     def write_output(self) -> str | None:
--> 261         xml_doc = self.build_tree()
    262 
    263         out_str: str | None

/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-08e6e056-b785-413d-82d1-61188028128b/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/xml.py in build_tree(self)
    479             if not self.attr_cols and not self.elem_cols:
    480                 self.elem_cols = list(self.frame_dicts[0].keys())
--> 481                 self.build_elems()
    482 
    483             else:

/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-08e6e056-b785-413d-82d1-61188028128b/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/xml.py in build_elems(self)
    566                 val = (
    567                     None
--> 568                     if self.d[col] in [None, ""] or self.d[col] != self.d[col]
    569                     else str(self.d[col])
    570                 )

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: If you're data allows you could use dicts instead of lists eg. `data = [('xy', {1:'value1', 2:'value2'}), ('yx', {1:'value3', 2:'value4'}), ...]`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I've put the full traceback in the answer

Comment: This line `if self.d[col] in [None, ""] or self.d[col] != self.d[col]` is causing the problem. This condition will give you a series of Booleans, not just one. Think you need to update this